# Was the unnamed techie in Dredd a cyborg?

Tags: movie, dredd

In Dredd, there is an [unnamed computer expert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dredd#Cast) (played by [Domhnall Gleeson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domhnall_Gleeson)) who appears to have mechanical eyes. There are a few scenes where it appears that we are looking either at or through his eyes and they are mechnical.

Furthermore, he appears to have scarring on his forehead, as if from an operation.

My questions:

1. Is he a cyborg?
2. How much of him is non-organic?
3. Is there a back story to explain how he came to be a cyborg?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, by definition he is a cyborg, which is an organic being that is enhanced by (or simply incorporates) artificial parts (or any type hybrid organism with both artificial and organic parts). Being that artificial eyes definitely require cybernetic technology, he would be appropriately called a [**cyb**-ernetic **org**-anism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyborg).

   Other people with cybernetic implants, such as cochlear implants, pacemakers, contemporary visual prostheses, electromechanical limb prostheses, surgically installed cameras/computer interfaces, etc., would also qualify as cyborgs.
2. No other parts of him are artificial.
3. His eyes were replaced after Ma-Ma tortured him and gouged out his eyes. Andersen saw this when she used her psychic abilities on him, realizing that he was a victim and obeyed Ma-Ma out of fear rather than a willing member of the clan.

Answer (score 3):

In the movie there's a flash-back scene when someone (the Doctor I think) is explaining to Dredd and Anderson how Mama took over Peach Trees.

> It show her pressing her thumbs into his eye sockets so he could have the implants.

As far as it's revealed it's only his eyes.

Comment: I think it's actually when Anderson scans his mind psychically when they find him hiding in the control room, and she decides to let him go.

Comment: @Monty129: yes, but it also shows this earlier when the doctor is explaining who Ma-Ma is (17:30 in).

Comment: I remember that scene now